# xbindkeys won't execute bash script

Tags: bash, keyboard-shortcuts, xbindkeys

I have a `bash` script for enabling and disabling wifi that I want to bind to shortcut:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $(rfkill list wifi | grep "Soft blocked: yes" | wc -l) -gt 0 ] ; then
    rfkill unblock wifi
    notify-send "Enabled Wireless"
else
    rfkill block wifi
    notify-send "Disabled Wireless"
fi
```

I have made the script executable by running:

```
chmod +x script.sh
```

In `.xbindkeysrc` I have:

```
"path/to/script.sh"
F1
```

After that I have run `xbindkeys` in terminal and tried to press  <kbd>F1</kbd>   but nothing happens.

I verified that script does work when executed manually. I tried different bind keys like  <kbd>Alt</kbd>  +  <kbd>y</kbd>  etc.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Have you checked the key F1 is correct? you can check with `xbindkeys -k`

Comment: @Akuseru it does now work when I set it to some combination like alt + y. So do I set a script to run `xbindkeys` on startup or is there a way to autostart it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my system is working by using Mod + F2

You can auto start xbindkeys by putting it in your .xinitrc/.xprofile file, or depending on your distro, there could be an auto start program that takes care of it, like gnome-session-properties in Ubuntu